# How does vscode recognize the path to the correct header file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I configure c_cpp_properties.json file in vscode, where the boost library header file is in /opt/voy-sdk/include/ as follows

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Linux",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/opt/voy-sdk/include/",
        "/opt/voy-sdk/include/**"
      ],
      "defines": [],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "cStandard": "c17",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I can do an automatic jump, too
[image: jump]

However, there will be a red wavy line in vscode indicating that the header file cannot be found
[image: can't find header file]

Comment: show the full path to that header. is it `/opt/voy-sdk/include/boost/beast/core.hpp`?

Comment: yes. it's the full header file path @starball

Comment: weird.... and your program compiles okay?

Comment: yes. But I did not use vscode to compile @starball

Comment: hm. try `"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",`

Comment: All the problems were solved when I switched to clangd